# How to fix 'too many indices for array' error with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to work on how a linearly nonseparable dataset in R^2 can be linearly separable in R^3 after a transformation via an appropriate kernel function.

```py
def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

def fn_kernel(x1, x2):
    """ Implements a kernel phi(x1,y1) = [x1, y1, x1^2 + y1^2] """
    return np.array([x1, x2, x1**2.0 + x2**2.0])

""" Generate linearly nonseparable dataset (in R^2) """
```

I converted the dataset to PCA.

```py
pca = PCA(n_components=2)  
X = pca.fit_transform(X_train)  
Y = pca.transform(X_test)
```

To print X, and Y:

```
print(X)
[[-1.25822621 -0.10589429]
[ 1.14574408  0.50555968]
[ 1.53943153 -0.89326919]
[-1.50951157 -0.35717965]
[ 0.58873174 -0.94771082]
[ 0.50077128  1.6531032 ]
[-1.00694085  0.14539106]]


print(Y)
[[-1.76079692 -0.608465  ]
[-0.00179943  1.15053249]
[-0.05624106  0.1998327 ]]
```

In here it returns an empty list, I don't know why?

```
A = X[np.where(Y == 0)]
B = X[np.where(Y == 1)]
print(A) -> []
print(B) -> []
```

and when I run this below code:

```
X0_orig = A[:, 0]
Y0_orig = A[:, 1]
```

It gives me an error: too many indices for array.

Comment: The error is because you try accessing the second dimension of an (empty) list which does not exist.

Comment: Is there zero's and one's in your X & Y arrays? If not it will return empty list and therefore you wont be able to index it.

Comment: @Eskapp, so what is the solution, I printed the `X`, and `Y`, and you can see the values. even I check with `less|greater than zero`, but still same problem

Comment: @Cr1064, as the `PCA` will not create exactly `1` or `0`, you can see the output of `X` and `Y`. Tell me the solution, what to do with?

Comment: there is no value in Y that is either 0 or 1, not sure what you expect to get with np.where

Comment: @micric, I want to use the `Kernel`, but I transformed my dataset to feature 2D vector, as you can see in `X`, and `Y`, none of the value is `0 or 1`, so what you suggest to fix this issue

Comment: it looks like you're confusing `Y`, which in your code is transformed `X_test`, with data labels